# The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0' (arm64) was not found

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, apple-m1

My structure of folders is

```
BulkyBook
/ BulkyBook.DataAccess
/ BulkyBook.Models
/ BulkyBook.Utility
/ BulkyBookWeb
```

Inside BulkyBook.DataAccess contains my ApplicationDbContext, my migrations and also the repository. And inside BulkyBook.Models contains my representation of the model.

I have a Macbook Pro M1 and when I try to run this command to create my database at my container.

```
dotnet ef update database --project ~/Documents/learning/bulky/BulkyBook.Models/BulkyBook.Models.csproj
```

This message appeared on terminal

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0' (arm64) was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      6.0.6 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Before all I ran this command on terminal

```
dotnet tool install dotnet-ef --global -a arm64
```

Comment: What is your target runtime version? I think arm64 is only supported for .NET 5.0 or later. So you can't target a .NET core 2.x application for arm64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seemingly your project targets NETCore.App version 2.0.0. Download  and install Microsoft.NETCore.App, version 2.0.0 runtime and try again.

If it doesn't work, setting your web project as startup project may resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you speaking to install the .NET 2? If yes, why?

Comment: No, I don't. It is .net core not .net framework

Comment: How can I set the project web as you said?

Comment: I ran `dotnet --info`

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.7 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.7 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Comment: In visual studio, right click on the project and select 'set as startup project'

Comment: This is my repository and all target framework are net 6
https://github.com/vagnerwentz/bulky

Comment: Thank you @m.r226 I seted the project as startup project, I deleted the "bin" and "obj" folders, I restored all projects and rebuild.